# Logout user via Keycloak REST API doesn't work

Tags: keycloak

I have issue while calling Keycloak's **logout** endpoint from an (mobile) application.

This scenario is supported as stated in [its documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#logout):

> /realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout

> The logout endpoint logs out the authenticated user.

> The user agent can be redirected to the endpoint, in which case the active user session is logged out. Afterward the user agent is redirected back to the application.

> **The endpoint can also be invoked directly by the application. To invoke this endpoint directly the refresh token needs to be included as well as the credentials required to authenticate the client**.

My request has following format:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<my_realm>/protocol/openid-connect/logout
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

refresh_token=<refresh_token>
```

but this error always occurs:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Server: WildFly/10
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 123
Date: Wed, 11 Oct 2017 12:47:08 GMT

{
  "error": "unauthorized_client",
  "error_description": "UNKNOWN_CLIENT: Client was not identified by any client authenticator"
}
```

It seems that Keycloak is unable to detect the current client's identity event if I've provided **access_token**. I've the used same **access_token** to access other Keycloak's APIs without any problems, like **userinfo**
(*/auth/realms/<my_realm>/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo*).

My request was based on this [Keycloak's issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-2476). The author of the issue got it worked but it is not my case.

I'm using Keycloak **3.2.1.Final**.

Do you have that same problem? Have you got any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Has anyone got a solution for Keycloak 4.* series?

Comment: Documentation link update: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#logout

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Finally, I've found the solution by looking at the Keycloak's source code: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/9cbc335b68718443704854b1e758f8335b06c242/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/endpoints/LogoutEndpoint.java#L169. It says:

> If the client is a public client, then you must include a "client_id" form parameter.

So what I was missing is the **client_id** form parameter. My request should have been:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<my_realm>/protocol/openid-connect/logout
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=<my_client_id>&refresh_token=<refresh_token>
```

The session should be destroyed correctly.

Comment: I tried this with Keycloak 4.4.0.Final and 4.6.0.Final and could not get it to work successfully.

Comment: From this answer, I don't understand what does your `client_id` map to in a Spring Web application? I tried 'IdToken.id', 'AccessTokenId.id' and also the 'context.tokenString' - every time I get the error message 'invalid client credentials'

Comment: In fact, ``access token`` is not needed, just the ``client_id`` and ``refresh_token`` is enough.

Comment: @Manh Ha can u please confirm where we needs to sent client_id and refresh_token in request body or as url parameter ?

Comment: @BhagvatLande: these params should be in (POST) request body, not in url.

Comment: thanks @ManhHa , I am struggling to found refresh token , can you please explain where did i found this , i try almost all ways .. if possible please reply asap . thanks again

Comment: @BhagvatLande: it depends on which flow of OpenID connect. In my case, it is "Resource owner" flow for which I just send a (POST) request to http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<my_realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token. I obtain something which looks like this: {
  "access_token": "<some_long_text_here",
  "expires_in": 300,
  "refresh_expires_in": 0,
  "refresh_token": "<some_other_long_text_here>",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "not-before-policy": 0,
  "session_state": "cefa0a94-3df5-4d25-affe-f1b517bae85c",
  "scope": "email profile"
} . This is where you can find refresh_token.

Comment: thanks @ManhHa i checked this it returns refresh token but it seems keycloak creating another new session for same user , this leads me in problem i don't want too create another session

Comment: actually i was struggling in logout same question posted

Comment: I don't know what your use case but generally when user is logged in (via one of OpenID Connect's flows, you should save his refresh token. At a later time, when you want to log him out, you use that same refresh token to logout. You should not use the login request above (http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/%3Cmy_realm%3E/protocol/openid-connect/token) to retrieve a (new) refresh token because Keycloak will create a new session for that request, as you've seen. If you can describe more about your system (which flow you are using), it might be that I will be able to tell a little bit more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187932/discussion-between-bhagvat-lande-and-manh-ha).

Comment: @ManhHa Where do you get "refresh_token" from to include in your "data"?

Comment: @ManhHa I see in the chat you said "I just send a (POST) request to localhost:8080/auth/realms/<my_realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token" . When I do that (with or without cliend_id in the payload), I get 400 code which is the same error taht means "no valid credentials"

Comment: @SwissNavy: you get the refresh token when you log user in (meaning you might have send a request to  localhost:8080/auth/realms/<my_realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token), the response of that request might look like this: 

<code>
{
  "access_token": "<access_token_value>",
  "expires_in": 299,
  "refresh_expires_in": 1799,
  "refresh_token": "<refresh_token_value>",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "not-before-policy": 0,
  "session_state": "<session_state_value>",
  "scope": "profile email"
}
</code>

You can find the refresh token in that response.

Comment: @ManhHa . Thanks, but I mean where is the refresh_token stored (if it's stored)? I did not find it in the cookies. I log in and browse the site for some time, now I want to logout, where can I retrieve this token from at this point? Hitting openid-connect/token just gives me `{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Invalid client credentials"}`, maybe I am not calling it right...

Comment: @SwissNavy: it depends on how you integrate with Keycloak: Which OpenID Connect flow (Implicit Flow/Authentication Flow/Resource Owner Password Grant/Client Credentials Grant), because I think that not all of these flows give you a refresh token. You might need to refer to the OpenID Connect protocol's docs for more information. What technology stack you are using is also important because certain library/framework might store differently the refresh token. Might I ask what flow + technology stack you are working on?

Comment: @ManhHa. I have a web container with Django 2.2 that talks to keycloak container( build using pulled jboss/keycloak image). All works fine for logging in, but for logout I need refresh_token so I call for it: `url_token = "http://<my IP>:8080/auth/realms/acc/protocol/openid-connect/token/"
    data = {'client_id' : '<client_id>', 'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
    r = requests.post(url_token, data = data)` and get
    `{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Invalid client credentials"}`. Also tried with username and password instead of client_id.

Comment: @ManhHa. Same response from curl POST. Some of my struggle is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58198713/how-to-log-out-from-keycloak-from-django-code

Comment: @ManhHa In my realm.json file I have this line:    "accessTokenLifespanForImplicitFlow" : 900 . Does this mean I am using Implicit Flow? If so, how should I logout? I did not write that app so I am somewhat guessing here..

Comment: I've never used Django (because I'm a Java guy ) but I try to look at the framework you are using (Social Core) for Keycloak implementation. I does not seem to store refresh token anywhere: https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/1d809941ab8a99af9e1bdf12bae548202c94eaa2/social_core/backends/keycloak.py . It'd be better you address your question to the library maintainers.

Comment: Your second question about the realm.json, I don't think that parameter means you are using implicit. You might want however analyse the network exchanges between  your app and Keycloak by using https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference if you are using Chrome. Look for a parameter grant_type, it should be the flow you are looking for.

Comment: @ManhHa Thanks. There's no grant_type in my network traffic. After the login my request.session contains this stuff: items: dict_items([('next', '/'), ('keycloak_state', 'k3edci3ZqYCdh7KXIGhJ6Wte32t3lRY4'), ('_auth_user_id', '37'), ('_auth_user_backend', 'social_core.backends.keycloak.KeycloakOAuth2'), ('_auth_user_hash', '073b9f72bb8f7eaf95c15da55a20006d9009a03c'), ('social_auth_last_login_backend', 'keycloak')]), I wonder if any of that can be used for logout call...

Comment: @SwissNavy: unfortunately no, you cannot use any of these to call the /logout endpoint.

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect now! My tokens are finally invalidated!

Answer (score 16):

Works with Keycloak 6.0.

Just for clarity: we do expire refreshToken, but accessToken IS STILL VALID while "Access Token Lifespan" time. Next time user tries to renew access token passing refresh token, Keycloak returns 400 Bad request, what should be catch and send as 401 Unauthorised response.

```
public void logout(String refreshToken) {
    try {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        requestParams.add("client_id", "my-client-id");
        requestParams.add("client_secret", "my-client-id-secret");
        requestParams.add("refresh_token", refreshToken);

        logoutUserSession(requestParams);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw e;
    }
}

private void logoutUserSession(MultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestParams, headers);
    String realmName = "your-realm-name";
    String url = "/auth/realms/" + realmName + "/protocol/openid-connect/logout";

    restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, Object.class);
    // got response 204, no content
}
```

Comment: How did you manage to also expire the accessToken?. My concern is that if the access token is still valid after logout then there is a security risk. How can I handle that?

Comment: usually accessToken is valid for short time, like 15 min. How to force to expire it, I don't know, ask a question in keycloak forum https://keycloak.discourse.group/

Comment: In my case, the API `auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo` gives 401 with access_token. I am using keycloak 7.01

Comment: @Cheeta you can configure refreshToken's and accessToken's lifetime on Keycloak configuration

Answer (score 16):

Finally. It worked for me. I made a REST call as shown below:

**Headers**:

```
{
 "Authorization" : "Bearer <access_token>",
 "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
```

**Request Body**:

```
{
    "client_id" : "<client_id>",
    "client_secret" : "<client_secret>",
    "refresh_token" : "<refresh_token>"
}
```

**Method**:

```
POST
```

**URL**:

```
<scheme>://<host>:<port>/auth/realms/<realmName>/protocol/openid-connect/logout
```

I received 200 as a response... If you do anything wrong you will get 401 or 400 errors. It's very tough to debug this issue. BTW my keycloak version is `12.0.4`

Let me know if the post is not clear or if you need more information.

Comment: Adding client_id and client_secret to request body might create security issue.Can we expose this variable on the browser or network?

Comment: This is, in general, used in server-side communication (Example: Gateway to Keycloak) in a secure channel (HTTPS). For the browser, maybe you can go with the 302 redirection method.

Answer (score 7):

in version 3.4 you need as `x-www-form-urlencoded` body key client_id, `client_secret` and refresh_token.

Comment: Sending client_id and client_secret in body is discouraged by RFC 6749, better to use HTTP Basic authentication instead. Only refresh_token needs to be sent in body, I checked that it works with Keycloak.

Answer (score 2):

FYI: OIDC spec and Google's implementation has a [token revocation endpoint](https://connect2id.com/products/server/docs/api/token-revocation)

It was implemented in Keycloak 10. See [Keycloak JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-5325) for details

Answer (score 2):

According to the code: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/endpoints/LogoutEndpoint.java#L106

This is how it worked for my SpringBoot FX app

GET http://loccalhost:8080/auth/realms/<my_realm>/protocol/openid-connect/logout?post_redirect_uri=your_encodedRedirectUri&id_token_hint=id_token

Comment: This works.. great. Less complicated than other solutions discussed here.

Answer (score 1):

This approach does not require any manual endpoint triggers. It relies on `LogoutSuccessHandler` and particularly on `OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler` that checks if `end_session_endpoint` is present on `ClientRegistration` bean.

By some circumstances `end_session_endpoint` is not used by default on most auth providers (except Okta) when paired with Spring Security, and we are left to inject it into `ClientRegistration` manually. The easiest way was to put it before `InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository` initialization, right after `application.properties` or `application.yaml` loading.

```java
package com.tb.ws.cscommon.config;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Configuration
public class ClientRegistrationConfig {

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean({ClientRegistrationRepository.class})
  InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository(
      OAuth2ClientProperties properties) {
    List<ClientRegistration> registrations =
        OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getClientRegistrations(properties)
            .values()
            .stream()
            .map(
                o ->
                    ClientRegistration.withClientRegistration(o)
                        .providerConfigurationMetadata(
                            Map.of(
                                "end_session_endpoint",
                                "http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/OAuth2/protocol/openid-connect/logout"))
                        .build())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(registrations);
  }
}
```

And in `WebSecurity`:

```java
package com.tb.ws.cscommon.config;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.web.logout.OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler;

@Slf4j
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  private final InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository registrationRepository;

  public WebSecurity(InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository registrationRepository) {
    this.registrationRepository = registrationRepository;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    String[] permitAccess = new String[] {"/", "/styles/**"};

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(permitAccess)
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .and()
        .logout(
            logout -> {
              logout.logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler());
              logout.invalidateHttpSession(true);
              logout.clearAuthentication(true);
              logout.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
            });
  }

  private LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler() {
    OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler handler =
        new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(registrationRepository);
    handler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8005/");

    return handler;
  }
}
```

By default, Spring Security appends query parameters `id_token_hint` and `post_logout_redirect_uri` onto `end_session_endpoint`. This can be changed with `OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler handler`. This can be used with social providers. Just have a relevant `end_session_endpoint` for each provider.

Properties file `application.yaml` used in this example:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: cs-common
  main:
    banner-mode: off
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          cs-common-1:
            client_id: cs-common
            client-secret: 03e2f8e1-f150-449c-853d-4d8f51f66a29
            scope: openid, profile, roles
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect_uri: http://127.0.0.1:8005/login/oauth2/code/cs-common-1
        provider:
          cs-common-1:
            authorization-uri: http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/OAuth2/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            token-uri: http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/OAuth2/protocol/openid-connect/token
            jwk-set-uri: http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/OAuth2/protocol/openid-connect/certs
            user-info-uri: http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/OAuth2/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
server:
  port: 8005
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8004/eureka
  instance:
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${instanceId:${random.value}}
```

To test we just kick Spring Security's default `GET /logout` endpoint from the UI.

Misc:

- Spring Boot 2.5
- Spring Cloud 2020.0.3
- Java 11
- Keycloak Server 13.0.1

Client settings:

- Standard Flow Enabled
- Implicit Flow Disabled
- Direct Access Grants Enabled

Someone, somewhere may find it helpful.

P.S. The app and its properties file are for learning

Comment: Thanks. It helped me. Couple of points to add:

1. We need to add `"http://127.0.0.1:8005/"` as another **Valid Redirect URIs** in Keycloak
2. Instead of using hardcoded `"http://127.0.0.1:8005/"`, we can use `"{baseUrl}/"` like `handler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("{baseUrl}/");`

Answer (score 1):

At least on newer versions of keycloak, when I authenticate I get back an `id_token` value which I can then use to perform a `GET` request to the `/logout` endpoint which terminates the session in the keycloak console

`https://example.com/realms/{realm_id}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?id_token_hint={id_token}`

I've found trying to do the POST to these endpoints just becomes a bit of a nightmare and is not very well documented.

The URL takes you to the standard KeyCloak user signout page and doesn't seem to throw any bad status codes if the `id_token_hint` value is no longer valid.

I don't bother showing the page to the user, I just perform the call on the backend once they click signout and take them to my own splash screen which is far easier to customize

Comment: This works fine for me. Just pass id_token_hint and it will logout user.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with Keycloak 4.4.0.Final and 4.6.0.Final. I checked the keycloak server log and I saw the following warning messages in the console output.

```
10:33:22,882 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-1) type=REFRESH_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=security-admin-console, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, grant_type=refresh_token, client_auth_method=client-secret
10:40:41,376 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-5) type=LOGOUT_ERROR, realmId=demo, clientId=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJqYTBjX18xMHJXZi1KTEpYSGNqNEdSNWViczRmQlpGS3NpSHItbDlud2F3In0.eyJqdGkiOiI1ZTdhYzQ4Zi1mYjkyLTRkZTYtYjcxNC01MTRlMTZiMmJiNDYiLCJleHAiOjE1NDM0MDE2MDksIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTQzNDAxMzA5LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vMTI3Lj, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_client_credentials
```

So how did build the HTTP request? First, I retrieved the user principal from the HttpSession and cast to the internal Keycloak instance types:

```
KeycloakAuthenticationToken keycloakAuthenticationToken = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) request.getUserPrincipal();
final KeycloakPrincipal keycloakPrincipal = (KeycloakPrincipal)keycloakAuthenticationToken.getPrincipal();
final RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext context = (RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext) keycloakPrincipal.getKeycloakSecurityContext();
final AccessToken accessToken = context.getToken();
final IDToken idToken = context.getIdToken();
```

Second, I created the logout URL as in the top stack overflow answer (see  above):

```
final String logoutURI = idToken.getIssuer() +"/protocol/openid-connect/logout?"+
            "redirect_uri="+response.encodeRedirectURL(url.toString());
```

And now I then build the rest of the HTTP request like so:

```
KeycloakRestTemplate keycloakRestTemplate = new KeycloakRestTemplate(keycloakClientRequestFactory);
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.put("Authorization", Collections.singletonList("Bearer "+idToken.getId()));
headers.put("Content-Type", Collections.singletonList("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
```

And also build the body content string:

```
StringBuilder bodyContent = new StringBuilder();
bodyContent.append("client_id=").append(context.getTokenString())
            .append("&")
            .append("client_secret=").append(keycloakCredentialsSecret)
            .append("&")
            .append("user_name=").append(keycloakPrincipal.getName())
            .append("&")
            .append("user_id=").append(idToken.getId())
            .append("&")
            .append("refresh_token=").append(context.getRefreshToken())
            .append("&")
            .append("token=").append(accessToken.getId());
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyContent.toString(), headers);
//   ...
ResponseEntity<String> forEntity = keycloakRestTemplate.exchange(logoutURI, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class); // *FAILURE*
```

As you can observed, I attempted many variations of theme, but I kept getting invalid user authentication.
Oh yeah. I injected the keycloak credentials secret from the `application.properties` into object instance field with @Value

```
@Value("${keycloak.credentials.secret}")
private String keycloakCredentialsSecret;
```

Any ideas from Java Spring Security experienced engineers?

*ADDENDUM*
I created a realm in KC called 'demo' and a client called 'web-portal'
with the following parameters:

```
Client Protocol: openid-connect
Access Type: public
Standard Flow Enabled: On
Implicit Flow Enabled: Off
Direct Access Grants Enabled: On
Authorization Enabled: Off
```

Here is the code that rebuilds the redirect URI, I forgot to include it here.

```
final String scheme = request.getScheme();             // http
final String serverName = request.getServerName();     // hostname.com
final int serverPort = request.getServerPort();        // 80
final String contextPath = request.getContextPath();   // /mywebapp

// Reconstruct original requesting URL
StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
url.append(scheme).append("://").append(serverName);

if (serverPort != 80 && serverPort != 443) {
    url.append(":").append(serverPort);
}

url.append(contextPath).append("/offline-page.html");
```

That's all

Comment: You are using which kind of grant_type for your login flow? I was using grant_type=password because it was a mobile client with a native (iOS) login form. Because of that, I had to POST to the endpoint but was not able to redirect user to Keycloak signout page.

It seems that you are developping a web application, have you try just redirect user to the sign out page of Keycloak: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#logout?

Comment: My grant type is 'public' and client protocol is 'openid-connect' and I am also using Vaadin 10 to secure a Java web application

Comment: I just added redirectURI code to my answer above. The other thing that Vaadin 10 has different logout mechanism compared to Vaadin 8. It uses a new Flow API. See here https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/advanced/tutorial-application-lifecycle.html I can confirm that Logout without Keycloak works, because I tested their own Vaadin Bakery Spring Security application. However, this does not log the user out of Keycloak and hence I was attempting to make a RESTful call to the Keycloak server to logout the user out and then close the Vaadin (Http) Session. Make sense? :-/

Comment: OpenID Connect (that Keycloak implements) use the same grant_type as OAuth2, so its value should be one of the following: https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/ . As I don't have yet any idea of why your code doesn't work, could you provide a sample Github repo to reproduce the problem? It will be easier for me or others can look at and maybe has a hint about that.

Comment: I am wondering if this should be a brand new stack overflow ticket. Should I create a new one?

Comment: Yes, I think so. My initial question was about a mobile client interacting with Keycloak server. Yours is Spring/Vaadin-related. The solution might be not the same.

Comment: I created a Github repo: https://github.com/peterpilgrim/acme-client-vaadin10-app (removed the sensitivities) and I asked a new Stack Overflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53541373/how-to-make-rest-call-logout-work-with-spring-boot-vaadin-10-and-keycloak-4

Comment: Note that idToken can be null.
If anyone will want to get token string, use context.getTokenString(); instead of context.getToken()

Answer (score 0):

In the JWT you have "session_state"

```
{
    "exp": 1616268254,
    "iat": 1616267954,
     ....
    "session_state": "c0e2cd7a-11ed-4537-b6a5-182db68eb00f",
    ...
}
```

After

```
public void testDeconnexion() {
        
        String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8080/auth";
        String realm = "master";
        String clientId = "admin-cli";
        String clientSecret = "1d911233-bfb3-452b-8186-ebb7cceb426c";
        
        String sessionState = "c0e2cd7a-11ed-4537-b6a5-182db68eb00f";

        Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .serverUrl(serverUrl)
                .realm(realm)
                .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret) 
                .build();

        String realmApp = "MeineSuperApp";      

        RealmResource realmResource = keycloak.realm(realmApp);
        realmResource.deleteSession(sessionState);      
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For keycloak 16 using feign client i'm using the following solution:

Feign Client:

```
@FeignClient(name = "KeycloakClient")
public interface KeycloakClient {
    @PostMapping(
          value = "/auth/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
          consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
      Response logout(
          @RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorizationHeader,
          @PathVariable(value = "realm") String realm,
          @RequestBody String body);
}
```

Calling the logout:

```
public void logout(String accessToken,String refreshToken,String realm,String clientId,String clientSecret){
    String logoutTemplate = "client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&refresh_token=%s";
    String logoutBody = String.format(
        logoutTemplate,
        clientId,
        clientSecret,
        refreshToken)
    keycloakClient.logout("Bearer " + accessToken,realm,logoutBody);
}
```