# Keycloak Refresh Token is coming NULL in case of logout API?

Tags: oauth, wildfly, access-token, servlet-filters, keycloak

I am using keycloak 4.8.3 and wildfly-14.0.1 in my Java Application. Facing problem in deleting session from Servelet Filter. Below are approaches which i tried.

**Approach 1:** 
I am using `HttpServletRequest.logout()` to delete session from keycloak.This approach is not working for me and i am getting `refresh-token` equal to `NULL`

**Approach 2:**
But when i trigger rest call using curl command with access token provided.

```
curl -X POST -k -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-i 'https://authserver/auth/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/logout' \
--data 'username=abc&password=def&client_id=client-id&grant_type=refresh_token&client_secret=a682049d-587c-4c38-a594-814f08b0ca7&refresh_token=<refresh_token>'
```

This approach2 working fine.

I am not sure why in case of Java ,I am getting refresh-token NULL? Below is the code

```
    KeycloakSecurityContext keycloakSecurityContext = (KeycloakSecurityContext)httpRequest.getAttribute( KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName() ); 
    if(keycloakSecurityContext instanceof RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext) { 
    RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext ksc = (RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext)keycloakSecurityContext; 
    RefreshToken refreshToken = ksc.getRefreshToken(); 
    RefreshToken refreshTokenDecoded = TokenUtil.getRefreshToken(refreshToken);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logout user via Keycloak REST API doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689034/logout-user-via-keycloak-rest-api-doesnt-work)

Comment: KeycloakSecurityContext keycloakSecurityContext = (KeycloakSecurityContext)httpRequest.getAttribute( KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName() ); if(keycloakSecurityContext instanceof RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext) 
{ 
RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext ksc = (RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext)keycloakSecurityContext; 
RefreshToken refreshToken = ksc.getRefreshToken(); 
RefreshToken refreshTokenDecoded = TokenUtil.getRefreshToken(refreshToken); // Getting as null. 
}

Comment: This is how i am trying to retrieve refresh token..

Comment: httpRequest.logout(); will logout from currently login session, why you want to get refresh token ?

Comment: For me httpRequest.logout() is not deleting keycloak session.

Comment: What is the Access Type set for your client ? if it is bearer-only, then refresh token will be null

Comment: curl -X GET "https://abc/api/getById/1" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: bearer <access_token>" is my curl command.