# How to get Refresh Token of KeyCloak in Spring Boot - Jhipster

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, keycloak

I have created MicroService(Spring Boot) App with Jhipster(having gateway + microservice + keycloak) , also configured KeyCloak.

everything is working fine , but i have problem in logout application , When i hit logout API from UI it will only logout from gateway (Not Destroying KeyCloak Session)

Note : Server Not saving any cookies on browser except JSESSIONID

I Need to logout user session from keyCloak.for that i go through below links

[Logout user via Keycloak REST API doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689034/logout-user-via-keycloak-rest-api-doesnt-work/46769801?noredirect=1#comment95842540_46769801)

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/logout.html

As per above links , I need to make POST request to KeyCloak which destroy user active Sessions.for that i call following API

```
POST http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<my_realm>/protocol/openid-connect/logout
```

refer link ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689034/logout-user-via-keycloak-rest-api-doesnt-work/46769801?noredirect=1#comment95842540_46769801) answer of @Manh Ha)

I need to add Access Token and Refresh Token in request body , I found Access token from Principal object , But I am struggling to found Refresh Token

Questions :

1) Where i found Refresh token (in spring Boot) ?

Answer (score 4):

Support for OIDC Logout was added in JHipster 5.8.0. You can upgrade your JHipster app or copy the code from [this PR](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/8757) into your code.

Comment: Thank you very much they have added logout functionality in latest release of Jhipster . I just updated Jhpistor-cli its working in newly created app . Thanks you saved my Day .