# python-keycloak package with KeycloakOpenID : logout does not work

Tags: client, token, keycloak, logout

I have a keycloak docker container (pulled image jboss/keycloak ) and a Django 2.2 web container. For integration of django with keycloak `social-auth-app-django` was used.  Login works fine. Now trying to implement logout using python-keycloak following instructions described here:

https://github.com/marcospereirampj/python-keycloak :

```
   from keycloak import KeycloakOpenID

    keycloak_openid = KeycloakOpenID(server_url="http://<my IP>:8080/auth/",
                        client_id="<client_id>",
                        realm_name="<my realm name>",
                        client_secret_key="<my secret>",
                        verify=True)
    config_well_know = keycloak_openid.well_know()
    token = keycloak_openid.token("<username>", "<password>")
    print(token) # all tokens returned ok

    userinfo = keycloak_openid.userinfo(token['access_token'])
    print ("userinfo:", userinfo) # userinfo returned ok 

    keycloak_openid.logout(token['refresh_token'])
```

in the container log:
`Some clients have been not been logged out for user <username> in <my realm name> realm: <client_id>`

No logout happens, still can browse the site.

What's missing? Thanks

**UPDATE**
Maybe I understood the problem. The token I get from  `keycloak_openid.token()` call is not the token that was generated for me at the moment of login. The only token that can be fed to `keycloak_openid.logout()` call for it to work is that original token ('refresh_token' key value of the token dict, to be specific). Calling `keycloak_openid.refresh_token()` also issues a new token which is rejected as logout credential. But the originally issued refresh_token does not seem to be stored anywhere - sessions, cookies or keycloak db. (Note: I did find `access_token`, it's in the django DB in `social_auth_usersocialauth` table, but I need `refresh_token`). However, it's dumped to the console output at the moment of login, so if I copy it and call   `keycloak_openid.logout()` with it, it does logout from keycoak. The question is where can I find that original refresh_token?

Answer (score 2):

I used to experience the same issue. What helped was

1. Going to `admin` page and location your user in the `realm`
2. open your browser's developer console and monitor the `networks`
3. Go to `sessions` tab on keycloak and click `log out`
4. Observe which end point is being called and mimic that in your python backend, with proper header in the request.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this question is outdated, but I managed to logout by this:

1. Add the following variables to `settings.py`:

```py
SOCIAL_AUTH_KEYCLOAK_LOGOUT_URL = 'https://your-keycloak/auth/realms/your-realm/openid-connect/logout'

SOCIAL_AUTH_KEYCLOAK_EXTRA_DATA=[("refresh_token","refresh_token")]
```

Now it will save the refresh token in `extra_data`.

2. Add into `urlpatterns` list in `urls.py`:

`url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),`

2. Add the logout view with communication code to `views.py`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout
import requests

def logout(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user
        if user.social_auth.filter(provider='keycloak'):
            social = user.social_auth.get(provider='keycloak')
            access_token=social.extra_data['access_token']
            refresh_token=social.extra_data['refresh_token']
            #logger.debug(access_token) # you can view the tokens
            #logger.debug(refresh_token)
            logout_request_data={"client_id": settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_KEYCLOAK_KEY, "refresh_token": refresh_token, "client_secret": settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_KEYCLOAK_SECRET}
            headers={"Authorization" : "Bearer "+access_token,"Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
            result=requests.post(settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_KEYCLOAK_LOGOUT_URL,data=logout_request_data,headers=headers)
    auth_logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

`result` code will be 204 on success.