# Logout from Keycloak does not logout Active Directory User

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect

We have integrated **KeyCloak server** with Azure **Active Directory** as Identity Provider for SSO Login.
Log-in is working fine. However we facing problem with log-out, When user logs-out from  web application, from our backend server side code we are making REST call to Keycloak server for below API.
`https://keycloaktest:8443/auth/realms/<realmName>/protocol/openid-connect/logout`
for this REST call we are getting 204 status code as response.

However when User tries to log-in in application again from browser it does not ask to enter credentials (active directory credentials).

In order to log-out User. We have access below URL
https://portal.azure.us/#home
and click log-out there.
https://portal.azure.us/Account/SignOut

Is there anyway to achieve this in backend i.e. when User clicks logout from browser

Answer (score 0):

Just ran across this myself. The answer provided here: [Logout user via Keycloak REST API doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689034/logout-user-via-keycloak-rest-api-doesnt-work) worked for me. Try adding client_id and refresh_token to your /logout request.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).